# Deploying Angular App to Github Pages with angular-cli-ghpages?

Tags: angular, github, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

These steps used to work.  First create the repository:

```
https://github.com/fireflysemantics/help-service-parts
```

Add the remote for it

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:fireflysemantics/help-service-parts.git
```

Add `angular-cli-ghpages`:

```
ng add angular-cli-ghpages
```

And deploy:

```
ng deploy --base-href=https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com/ --cname=help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com
```

After doing this it does create the cname record and I see all the files in the gp-pages branch:

```
https://github.com/fireflysemantics/help-service-parts
```

However when looking at the settings the custom domain field is not populated with the cname domain, and it says the site is ready to be published:

```
Your site is ready to be published at http://fireflysemantics.github.io/help-service-parts/.
```

But it does not appear at the url:

http://fireflysemantics.github.io/help-service-parts/

I have DNS set to resolve it on:

```
https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com
```

Also.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you try removing the slash from the url? `ng deploy --base-href='https://help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com'`

Comment: I think that was it - Thank you!!!

Comment: Posted as the answer. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of angular-cli-ghpages. The combined usage of the parameters `--cname` and `--base-href` is not expected.

This should work if you do **not** want to use your own domain:

```sh
ng deploy --base-href=/help-service-parts/
```

And this is what you set when you have your own domain:

```sh
ng deploy --cname=help-service-parts.fireflysemantics.com
```